# How to update the firebase data after editing rows in a DataGrid from MUI?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, datagrid, material-ui

It is known that you can simply add `editable: true/false` and a row gets edited and it changes. However how can you edit a row AND update the firebase when that is done ? as soon as you refresh or leave the page and come backs it will load the same data because nothing is getting updated in firebase when you "Edit" something.

**EDIT 2**

Apparently what I was trying to do is only for MUI-Pro so back to where I was. This so far selects properly the row and just need to enable the edit and those edited values parse them down to the update but idk how to do get those values or how to set it up in "edit mode"

```
{
field: "edit", width: 70, sortable: false, disableColumnMenu: true,
      renderHeader: () => {
        return (
          <IconButton
          onClick={() => {
            const selectedIDs = new Set(selectionModel);
            estudiantes.filter((x) =>
            selectedIDs.has(x.id)).map( x => {
              const temporalQuery = db.collection("usuarios").doc(user.uid).collection("estudiantes").doc(x.uid);
              temporalQuery.update({
                nombre: "edited name variable",
                colegio: "edited school variable",
                grado: "edited course variable"
              })
            })
          }}
          >
            <EditSharpIcon />
          </IconButton>
        );
      }
    }
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Have a look at `onRowEditCommit` if you're using full row edit or  `onCellEditCommit` in `DataGrid`

Comment: I'll be using on cell edit. honestly I was gonna do action buttons but when I saw the documentation for that one I decided not to. Is too complex for me yet.

Comment: @NearHuscarl would definitely use [Row editing](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/editing/#row-editing) after checking it out. But I didn't found a way to update data though

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6fspi?file=/demo.js) currently trying to make it work without the firebase update and then I'll try to make it work with firebase.